# How can two applications communicate?

Tags: android

I'm building two Android apps. Now I want the first app to get a single value from the database of the second app.

So, for the second app, storage values in your local database double in value.
The first app should get this value.

Is there a way to do this and is there a way to do this never using Web Server ?

Comment: are both apps running on same machine?

Comment: yes the apps is installed in the same smartphone

Answer (score 3):

> So the second app, storage in your local database 1 Double value. The first app should to get this value.

You could:

- Add a `ContentProvider` to the second app, which the first app then queries to get this value, or
- Add a bound `Service` to the second app, which the first app binds to, then makes some API call on that service to get this value